# How to repair vmx file corrupted at VMWare?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

When I started the virtual machine under VMware I received a message saying that the vmx file is corrupt. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Thanks for your effort.  It's look like you are trying to provide solution instead of a question.  If that's the case, could you help to edit the post with https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer this guidance?

Comment: You have right, I described how to solve the problem because I had such. Thanks for your suggestion. So how I can now select option "Answer your own question"? I don't see that.

Comment: That button only available for new question.  Maybe you can edit your question to "question" only, and put the solution as answer.  However, it seems you cannot mark _your answer_ as answer immediately, but I forgot how many days it need to wait.  You will see it when you post the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Simple and fast way to fix a corrupted vmx file.

We need to use vmware-vdiskmanager.exe for that purpose. It is installed together with vmware.exe in professional version. The Insalator is available at: [VMware Workstation Pro](https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/workstation-evaluation.html). We can use a 30 day trial.

Once VMware Workstation Professional is installed.

Execute step by step:

1. Open the command line (cmd.exe) as administrator
2. Navigate to the local installation of your VMware (mine is the default C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation)
3. Type the following command >> vmware-vdiskmanager.exe –R “the fully qualified path to your corrupt vmdk”
4. Hit Enter
5. Run VMware.exe
6. Navigate to File > New Virtual Machine

Check Custom (advanced) option

[image]

Select appropriate hardware compatibility

[image]

Click button next

[image]

Click button next

[image]

Point locations and enter virtual machin name the same as was corrupted file vmx.

[image]

Click the button NEXT all the time (we can set parameters of the machine). When we arrive at the wizard to the below picture, we need to set disk as use an existing virtal disk.

[image]

Click button next, select an existing corrupted disk and in the next step click button Finish. Now we can run our virtual machine.

Comment: hey,I keep getting access denied,this app cannot run in this computer error..you have any idea on this??Please help

Comment: Sorry, but if I `Point locations and enter virtual machin name the same as was corrupted file vmx.` Vmware rightly warn be because the wmx file already exists!

Comment: running vmware-vdiskmanager.exe gave me an error `Diskname or some other argument is missing.`

However i just continued creating a new VM using existing VMDK and it just worked fine